# How to set preselected value in ng-option?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have id from the city that is supposed to be selected in dropdown list, but I can`t manage to preselect it. Should I select it from directive or is there any other way?

```
<select  ng-model="cityId" ng-options="city.name for city in cities"></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your ng-options to this:

```
city.id as city.name for city in cities
```

if you fetch the cities and don't know the ID's
you could say in your javascript success function (which returns the cities):

```
$scope.cityId = the_cities[0].ID
```

to set the first as selected
Else you could just say:

```
$scope.cityId = 1; //or anything that exists
```

Comment: Do not use ng-init on your select. Check the documentation on ng-init. It is for evaluating an expression in the current scope. It is not to set a value.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use `select as` part for that, provided `id` is respective property on city object you would do:

```
ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in cities"
```

Otherwise you need to provide same object reference (of city object in the array) as the ng-model (if not using `track-by`).

When using `track-by` you would do:

```
ng-options="city.name for city in cities track by city.id"
```

and set the model as:

```
$scope.cityId = {id:'CITY1'};
```

When track by is used you do not need to worry about object references and it will actually have the value property of options reflecting exact id (unlike `select as` which keeps an internal map with index). This is helpful when doing form posts. But you should be careful not to mix it with `select as` since both are meant for different purposes and the implementation conflicts each other.

Comment: trackby is one of the most hidden features of angular ng-select. If you could provide an exemple of how to init ng-select with a trackby, everyone would benefit of it ;) !