# AngularJS + dropdown menu is not getting its default value "select..." assigned

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I gather data to populate a dropdown from calling an API method. Getting the data works.

My issue occurs when I am trying to assign a meeting id that does not have a match in the returned list. In this instance, I want to display the dropdown with all the meetings available, but at the top and displaying a simple text that reads: "Select Meeting".

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but all I get to achieve is to have the dropdown  with the values, but the first option blank, then the second option is "Select Meeting", I am not sure how to force the "Select Meeting" option to the top of the list, when we could not match the passed meeting id parameter.

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:51225/bla/bla/?meetingid=50985&email=myemail@.com
```

**AngularJS Controller Code:**

```
$scope.fetchList = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/bla/bla/bla/method',
      data: {}
    }).then(function(res) {


      $scope.MeetingList = res.data.data;

    }, function(error) {
      $scope.Message = 'An error occurred, please try again';
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="meeting-list" ng-model="selectedMeeting" ng-change="GetValue()">
  <option value="">-Select Meeting-</option>
  <option ng-repeat="meeting in MeetingList" value="{{meeting.MeetingID}}">{{meeting.MeetingName}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have a recommendation how to work this around?

Thank you.

Comment: if you change your options population with ng-options, does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510261/how-to-set-preselected-value-in-ng-option

Comment: Hi, I have not used ng-options. How do you assign meeting id as the value, and meeting name as the displayable value using ng-options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set preselected value in ng-option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510261/how-to-set-preselected-value-in-ng-option)

Comment: You can see the accepted answer to the question in the previous comment

Comment: Thank you, I tried changing to ng-options and this change impacts how the app works right now, more changes that anticipated. I would prefer to stick to ng-repeat if possible. I thought there was a way to be able to remove the blank line from the options, but if there is none. I understand and I can close this question. Than you.